# Horizontal scrollbar not working

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, perltk

```
use Tk;

my $mw=new MainWindow;

$mw->geometry("1024x768");

$mw->Scrolled("Text", -scrollbars => "s", -width => 30,-height=>10)->pack( );

MainLoop;
```

I need the help.The horizontal scrollbar is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "not working". When I execute your script I'll get a window with a text box and a scrollbar at the bottom.

Comment: Yes i also get a scroll bar.But when i enter text with length more than width of text box,the scrollbar dose not appear.The text goes down another line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the wrap mode of the text widget? If it's configured to wrap on word or character boundaries, the horizontal scrollbar won't ever be needed. For me, the default wrapping mode is `char` (i.e., wrap lines at character boundaries, like a terminal does) so I guess that's the default for you too, despite the fact that you're wanting it to be `none` (the only setting where a horizontal scrollbar is useful).

Add `-wrap => "none",` to your options to `Scrolled`.

Comment: The `word` style of wrapping is more word-processor/web-browser like, working particularly well when using a variable-width font.